# How to Update ENV variable permanently in jenkins through jenkinsfile, to be used in successful builds

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-groovy

need my ENV variable to update its value through jenkinsfile and be able to use the updated value in next jenkinsbuild

I created an Environment variable on the jenkins node

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmAXE.png)

I'm updating the variable,getting this output
`

```
println "${env.EOD_ID}"

env.EOD_ID = "23ba9d9e-93ce-4b46-a81d-8784794d81b1-test"

println "${env.EOD_ID}"
```

`

output :

```
test
10:29:31  [Pipeline] echo
10:29:31  23ba9d9e-93ce-4b46-a81d-8784794d81b1-test
```

but when i run the next build
it does not have the value 23ba9d9e-93ce-4b46-a81d-8784794d81b1-test

Answer (score 0):

You can't update the environment variables like that. If you are using the [EnvInject Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/) you can use the following script to update the Environment variable.

```
ef persistInfo(){

    def jenkins = Jenkins.instance
    def jobA = jenkins.getItemByFullName("$JOB_NAME")
    def prop2 = jobA.getProperty(org.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.EnvInjectJobProperty);
    def con = prop2.getInfo().getPropertiesContent();

    def str = "NewValue"
      
    def prop = new EnvInjectJobPropertyInfo("", str , "", "", "", false)

    def propNew = new org.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.EnvInjectJobProperty(prop)
    propNew.setOn(true)
    propNew.setKeepBuildVariables(true)
    propNew.setKeepJenkinsSystemVariables(true)
    jobA.addProperty(propNew)

    jobA.save();
}
```